# How can I see file events of all processes matching those with keyword in path?

Tags: monitoring, strace, inotify

How can I see file events of all processes matching only those with keyword in path ?

Here is my typical usecase. I'm investigating why Docker can't authorize with 3rd-party service using credentials that I put to `~/.aws/credentials`. I suspect I put credentials to wrong location and would like to know where docker is really looking for them.

I suspect I can use `inotify` to achieve it but extensive reading of manuals didn't give me an answer. The best I could find was watching events to *particular file*.

Comment: if there's a parent process that kicks off this sequence, you could start it under `strace -f ...` http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace and watch for file openings